# Updated relationship data not sent to server with Ember and Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I took over an app written in Ember, which is fairly new to me. Also, I learned Ember Octane, but the app is using Ember 3.2. It also uses Ember Data with the default JSONAPISerializer.

In my app there's a `project` model, and each model belongs to a `creator`, which is an instance of a `person`:

In `models/projects.js`:

```
creator: DS.belongsTo('person', { inverse: null }),
```

I want to update this relationship data (assign a new `creator` to the `project`) in a controller method:

```
project.set('creator', otherPerson); // or project.creator_id = otherPerson.id;
project.save();
```

The POST request is successful, but there isn't any relationship data in the payload, hence the creator isn't updated. The payload looks roughly like this in Chrome DevTools:

```
data: {id: "d9803dff-5b3f-4802-b8ac-7fe1adf369de", attributes: {,…}, type: "projects"}
  -> attributes: {,…}
       abstract: "Quod Iure sequi velit. Aliquam ut dolorem. Sapiente nulla esse. Perspiciatis ipsum quas. Occaecati quis nihil. Unde tenetur est."
       title: "consequatur pariatur facere quia"
       url: null
  id: "d9803dff-5b3f-4802-b8ac-7fe1adf369de"
  type: "projects"
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: your code looks good, this should work! Verify that `otherPerson` is *really* a creator Record (and not a `PromiseObject` or any kind of wrapper)! And it must already be saved (so it has an id). Also ember `3.2` is pretty good, it should be fairly easy to upgrade to`3.24`.
Can you share the payload that is sent to the backend?

Comment: I added the payload to the question. `otherPerson` is a `person` record. It has an ID (which is the value I expect it to have),

Comment: Did you customized `ProjectSerializer` or `ApplicationSerializer`? Ember Data should persists the has-one side of a relationship by default. Maybe there is some customization, which prevents this? A reproduction as Ember Twiddle or Codesandbox would be very helpful as well if you could create one.

Comment: That's it, thank you! I hadn't even seen a serializer in Ember before, but actually there was a `ProjectSerializer` containing a method that prevented the creator relationship to be included in the payload.